# Why $_Post is discouraged when program a web app

Tags: php, post, frameworks

I read in a post related to a WordPress trouble, people in the post was discussing that `$_POST` is not recommended to be used when there is option such as `$this->property->post('value')` in the framework.

Are there any specific reason for not using `$_POST` in the context of the best coding practice or its not an issue at all.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with $_POST. You only in context with frameworks have a layer of abstraction between.

Comment: If you don´t use $_POST, then how would you retrieve data from a form? think about it ;D the only other way would be using $_GET, which is more insecure as it reveals the parameters in the address bar.

Comment: ... apart from having to sprinkle your code with `if(isset)`.

Comment: This is a valid question in regards to framework best practices.

Comment: aleation, if my question did not state clearly, its about $_POST and the other method and not about get, which I know its not as secure as $_Post. That's also the reason you did not see $_Get appear in my question. Thanks

Comment: Adam, I've removed the in-question commentary. If you must, place it in a comment underneath the question (although I think it's irrelevant to the question. Plus, keep in mind that people are here on their own accord volunteering their time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it is possible to use `$_POST` as it is, but than you maybe lose some features of your framework, e.g. you have a more OOP form of using your request parameters when using your frameworks abstraction layer, or maybe your framework automatically trims user inputs. That benefits would get lost.

Internally, your framwork **must** also use `$_POST`, otherwise it couldn't get the request data.

So, if you use `$_POST` directly,  you jump over an abstraction layer that normally is seen as a feature of the framework.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using any kind of framework, you should stick to it's internal conventions and use it's capabilities, or else there is no point of using it.

Comment: short and good answer, but Bernhard did a more detailed answer. thanks, up for you as well!

Answer (score 1):

I know that certain frameworks like flourish discourage the use of super global's because they have their own methods in place for handling them.

Things like fget, ftoken, fsession and fpost are examples of abstracted versions of them. I forget exactly why they are different or what flourish does to them but I'm sure you can find more info here.

http://flourishlib.com/docs

Same thing holds true in other frameworks like code igniter ... etc. Not sure if that helps answer your question or not thought

Comment: It did in a way, but Bernhard did a more detailed answer. thanks, up for you as well!

Answer (score 1):

*As long as you live under my roof, you'll abide by my rules.*
- Anonymous

It's best to follow a framework's best practices as doing otherwise will most likely **bypass inherent benefits**. For instance, a framework may have a way to automatically trim user input through configuration. In that case, the framework will most likely only apply the trim to its internal representation of posted data. Another example may be overriding the framework's method in **unit testing**. If you use the `$_POST` variable directly, you'll usurp any "injection" that may be in use.

Comment: good answer, but Bernhard did a more targeted answer. thanks, up for you as well!